# Gunicorn ImportError: No module named polls

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm installing a previously built Django website on a new server using gunicorn and nginx.

`/home/ragequittech/manage.py runserver` runs fine, however, when I shut it down and run `/home/rageqquittech/ragequittech gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8030 wsgi:application` I get:

```
[2018-04-12 01:36:06 +0000] [1842] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2018-04-12 01:36:06 +0000] [1842] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8030 (1842)
[2018-04-12 01:36:06 +0000] [1842] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-04-12 01:36:06 +0000] [1846] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1846
[2018-04-11 20:36:06 +0000] [1846] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ragequittech/ratequittech/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ragequittech/ratequittech/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
[2018-04-11 20:36:06 +0000] [1846] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1846)
[2018-04-12 01:36:06 +0000] [1842] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-04-12 01:36:06 +0000] [1842] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

**wsgi.py**:

```
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = '/home/ragequittech/ragequittech/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Output with `print sys.path` appended before `get_wsgi_application()` in `wsgi.py`**

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8030 wsgi:application
[2018-04-14 20:55:44 +0000] [21821] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2018-04-14 20:55:44 +0000] [21821] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8030 (21821)
[2018-04-14 20:55:44 +0000] [21821] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-04-14 20:55:44 +0000] [21825] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21825
['/home/ragequittech/ratequittech', '/usr/bin', '/home/ragequittech/polls', '/home/ragequittech/home', '/home/ragequittech/blog', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/ragequittech/ragequittech/']
[2018-04-14 15:55:44 +0000] [21825] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ragequittech/ratequittech/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 366, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/ragequittech/ratequittech/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named polls
[2018-04-14 15:55:44 +0000] [21825] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21825)
[2018-04-14 20:55:44 +0000] [21821] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-04-14 20:55:44 +0000] [21821] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

snippet from **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'polls',
    'home',
    'blog',
    'podcast',
]
```

These apps exist within `/home/ragequittech/` directory. I thought it may have been an issue with the python path but that didn't seem to help. I included the following setup.py in the polls app and ran `python setup.py develop` but that didn't help either:

**setup.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='polls',
      version='1.0',
      packages=find_packages())
```

I know that the issue is that the apps aren't "installed" but I haven't found the right recipe for alleviating it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to print the`sys.path` just before the `get_wsgi_application()` in `wsgi.py` and post that?

Comment: Hi Will, just edited the post description accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your apps exist in the `/home/ragequittech` directory, make sure that is on the `PYTHONPATH` before you start gunicorn.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/ragequittech
```

It looks as though the `wsgi.py` module is in the `/home/ragequittech/ragequittech` subdirectory. So make sure you fully qualify `wsgi.py` when running the gunicorn command, and run it from the top level directory.

```
# Start from /home/ragequittech, and note qualified name
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8030 ragequittech.wsgi:application
```

Comment: It turns out that while I had set my `PYTHONPATH` previously, it looks like it only updated for python2, whereas my application was running on python3. I set it again and it updated python3 this time, which solved the issue. Thanks for all the help!